# how to parse this date in java

Tags: java, parsing, date

please tell me how to parse this date: "29-July-2012"

I try:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

but it doesn't works. I get the following exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "29-July-2012"
```

Comment: Try `dd-MMMM-yyyy`. See link for similar format: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4216767/1449199

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to mention the Locale as well...

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(string);
```

Answer (score 3):

In your String, the full format is used for month, so according to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html you should be using MMMM as suggested in Baz's comment.

The reason for this can be read from the API docs.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#month states that for month it will be interpreted as text if there are more than 3 characters and
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#text states that the full form (in your case 'July' rather than 'Jul') will be used for 4 or more characters.

Answer (score 2):

Try this (Added Locale.ENGLISH parameter and long format for month)

```
package net.orique.stackoverflow.question11815659;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Question11815659 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy",
                    Locale.ENGLISH);
            System.out.println(sdf.parse("29-July-2012"));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `split()` function with the **delimiter** `"-"`

```
String s = "29-July-2012";

String[] arr = s.split("-");

int day = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
String month = arr[1];
int year = Integer.parseInt(arr[2]);

// Now do whatever u want with the day, month an year values....
```

Comment: Ohh sorry for the typo...and thanks for tracing it out... thanks

Comment: That's not much better. Have a close look ;)

Comment: Lesson i learnt.... never try posting in stackoverflow... when doing official work..............

Answer (score 0):

Create a StringTokenizer. You first need to import the library:

```
import Java.util.StringTokenizer;
```

Basically, you need to create a delimeter, which is basically something to seperate the text. In this case, the delimeter is the "-" (the dash/minus).

Note: Since you showed the text with quotations and said parse, i'm assuming its a string.

Example:

```
//Create string
String input = "29-July-2012";

//Create string tokenizer with specified delimeter
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input, "-");

//Pull data in order from string using the tokenizer
String day = st.nextToken();
String month = st.nextToken();
String year = st.nextToken();

//Convert to int
int d = Integer.parseInt(day);
int m = Integer.parseInt(month);
int y = Integer.parseInt(year);

//Continue program execution
```

Comment: lmao, my bad, I would use an enum that stores the month as a string and a method that converts it to a number. I wrote it pretty quickly, but you get the idea.